# when record is deleted in gridview when we press backspace button the record is back

Tags: asp.net, gridview

When record is deleted in gridview when we press backspace button the record is back; when click that record the error message no records at rows 0 is found.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have any other facts you'd like to inform us about?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when you delete the record, you reload the page and in essence create a new entry in the browser's history.  The backspace key does the same thing as clicking the back button in the browser, and so you're getting what you asked for: the last page.

Answer (score 0):

"Backspace" is the browsers back button.  You're reading from the browser's cache.

When you click on the link, then that's a postback.  And since the record has really been deleted on the server, you get the no records found error.